# How does logging in managed VMs work?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-managed-vm, managed-vm

I'm reading [Google's docs on logging in managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/install/appengine_install), and they're rather thin on detail, and I have more questions than answers after reading:

- Files in `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs` are picked up automatically it says – is this path pre-existing or do you also have to `mkdir -p` it?
- Do I have to deal with log rotation/truncation myself?
- How large can the files be?
- If you write a file ending in `.log.json` and some bit of it is corrupt, does that break the whole file or will Google pick up the bits that can be read?
- Is there a performance benefit/cost to log things this way, over using APIs?

**UPDATE:** I managed to have logs show up in the log viewer, but only when logging files with the `.log` suffix, whenever I try `.log.json` they are not being picked up and I can't see any errors anywhere. The JSON output seems fine, and conforms to the requirement of having one object per line. Does anyone know how to debug this?

Comment: So I've gone ahead with the #yolo approach, simply redirecting output to two files under `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs`. Now, despite using this path, the logs actually end up under `/var/log/app_engine/app/custom_logs`, which I verified by SSHing into the instance and looking around. These logs show up nowhere in the Log Viewer.